# Getting primary key value from database table of corresponding selected row item in DataGrid using WPF

Tags: wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I have a DataGrid, bound to Database table, I need to select the primary key value from database table of corresponding content of selected row in DataGrid ..How to do it ? please Help ..

Comment: Hope this question is clear !

Comment: Post some code please!